# How do I declare a table with a string column that has a non null default value in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

What do I need to add to make sure this table is created with the 'name' field as non null but with a value of ""?

```
  CREATE TABLE stuff (id serial primary key, name varchar(64)  <-- what goes here??
```

Comment: See the example in the manual with the explanation "*Assign a literal constant default value for the column name*": https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXAMPLES

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard SQL applies:

```
CREATE TABLE stuff (
  id serial primary key, 
  name varchar(64) not null default ''
);
```

It's possible you attempted to use double quotes to specify the text literal like this `""`, which will explode. Postgres uses single quotes to delimit text literals, like this `''`.

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6abdb).

Comment: What does this mean?NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "stuff_seq" for serial column "stuff.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "stuff_pkey" for table "stuff"

Comment: @user740521 postgres handles auto incrementing types like `serial` by creating a separate `sequence` definition to which to table refers. most other databases handle it internally within the table's definition. The index creation is automatic too. Again, other databases do this silently. Just ignore these notifications..